# Photoshop CS4 path problem

Tags: path, adobe-photoshop, layers

i'm having a strange problem with photoshop:

i'm creating a new layer then use the path tool for drawing something.
the new path will then only show up under "paths" but the current layer remains empty.
shouldn't it show up there being labelled as "shape"?

what i want is creating a path, apply layer styles to it and keep the possibilty to change that path with layer styles applied.

seems like some setting was changed inside my cs4

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Don't treat this as an answer, but as support for @Fuxi's answer (I can't post pictures in a comment AFAIK)*

---

**This is the palette that he's referring to:**

[image]

Comment: I think Fuxi and Fuxi are actually the same person :)

Comment: I never thought they weren't. My comment was for the benefit of and directed at others who might come across this question in the future. Fuxi had already figured out the answer and knows what the palette looks like. ;)

Answer (score 0):

i managed to find out by myself: in brush mode there's a row of 3 icons at the top of the screen: shape layers, paths and one disabled.
the icon was set to paths and changing it to "shape" brings back the "shape" in current layer.

Comment: When you make a pure path, it does not actually exist within the image, unless you use it to make a selection, stroke it, etc.

Comment: See my answer for this comment.